# Sum of integers in excel

Tags: excel

I have a simple query in excel. I would like the sum of numbers in three different sheets into fourth excel sheet. I get an error message when when one cell has NULL value like minus sign.

Sheet1 = 1

Sheet2 = 2

Sheet3 = -

Sheet4 = Sheet1!A1+Sheet2!A1+Sheet3!A1

I would like to have 3 as an answer but I get #**Value** error message. How should I adjust formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sheets are contiguous and in order you can use:

```
=SUM(Sheet1:Sheet3!A1)
```

[image]

Where Sheet1 is the left most and Sheet 3 the right most of the three sheets with Sheet2 between.

If the sheets are not contiguous then you can use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&{"Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3"}&"'!A1"),"<>"))
```

[image]

With Office 365 and its dynamic arrays we can simplify the second with:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("'"&{"Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3"}&"'!A1"))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have different names of the sheet. In the actual file I have formula;
=SUM('CAT I'!O7+'CAT II'!O7+'CAT III'!O7+CATIV!O7+CATIVb!O7)

Comment: That is fine, just switch out the `Sheet#` for the correct sheet names.  It will work with different sheet names.  So the INDIRECT portion would be `INDIRECT("'"&{"CAT I","CAT II","CAT III","CATIV","CATIVb"}&"'!O7")`

Comment: And the 3D sum, if contiguous would be: `=SUM('CAT I':'CATIVb'!O7)`

Comment: Hi Scott. Thanks for your solution. Small comment.
With contiguous file, your mentioned formula worked with a small change else it gave error msg #NAME? Adjusted formula is:
=SUM('CAT I:CATIVb'!O7)
Secondly, other formula without contiguous file only work in one cell. If I drag the formula to other cells the the value O7 is not automatically changed. Could you have a solution for this as well?

Comment: for the INDIRECT to make it draggable: `INDIRECT("'"&{"CAT I","CAT II","CAT III","CATIV","CATIVb"}&"'!O"&ROW(O7)`

Comment: Hi Scott. Did you check this yourself. It is not working for me. 
Secondly I would like to drag it to both rows and columns as tables are big.

Comment: Then use: `INDIRECT("'"&{"CAT I","CAT II","CAT III","CATIV","CATIVb"}&"'!" & ADDRESS(ROW(O7),COLUMN(O7))`

Comment: one note.  If you are going to use this over many cells, ie more than 10K then use the formula that was given by Jeremy,  Address and Indirect are both volatile and as such will re calc everytime the there is a change in Excel, which may make the overall user experience to be poor.

Comment: Thanks both of you for this support.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the null cell value it's in number format. Maybe the "-" is text value so you get that #Value error

Comment: Yes, it is a text value. Just added DASH to show as empty. Now I would like the formula to read it as 0. Is this possible?

Comment: No. What I ment is that the formula should assume the dash value as 0 and I get the final answer 3.

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to treat something where taking its value gives an error as 0 (and otherwise just take its value), you can do so with the `iferror` function. You can then build up your sum as follows. I am not disagreeing with the proposal of using SUM. I am showing an option, and letting you add IFERROR to your repertoire.

```
=iferror(value(Sheet1!A1),0)+iferror(value(Sheet2!A1),0)+iferror(value(Sheet3!A1),0)
```

Comment: Hi Jeremy. You formula does not work but it works if I change it to the following;
=IF(ISNUMBER(CATI!A1),CATI!A1,0)+IF(ISNUMBER(CATII!A1),CATII!A1,0)+IF(ISNUMBER(CATIII!A1),CATIII!A1,0)

Comment: Full disclosiure: I tested it on Google Sheets, where it did work. What does it do on Excel? I can take it down or amend it. I just tested on LibreOffice calc, and it worked there too.

Comment: Hi Again. Sorry it was my fault. I was writing it wrongly. Now I checked again and it works. Thanks for reminding me and your efforts to support me :-).